# How to print length of each word in a string before the each Word

Tags: c, string

I want to print the length of each word in a string.

I have tried but not getting right answer. After running the code it will print the length of each word after the word instead of printing before the each word.

```
char str[20] = "I Love India";

int i, n, count = 0;
n = strlen(str);

for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0') {
        printf("%d", count);
        count = 0;
    } else {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        count++;
    }
}
```

I except the output is `1I 4Love 5India`, but the actual output is `I1 Love4 India5`.

Comment: Then you need to print the count before the word. First: remember where you are in string. Second: Count the number of of words. Print the count. Print the remembered word (you can use `printf("%.*s", length, pointer);`). Then increase your position in string.

Comment: They way you are doing it now the count can only be prined after the word. Go back to your laboratory and think how to print it before the word. Needs a different approach.

Comment: You might be interested in learning about the [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function.

Comment: @HareramShah: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtok as [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) sugested. You may want to make a copy of the original string as strtok modifies the passed string. Also strtok is not thread-safe and must be replaced with strtok_r when working with multi-threaded programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* for strtok */
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[20] = "I Love India";
    int n;

    char* tok = strtok(str, " ");

    while (tok != NULL) {
        n = strlen(tok);
        printf("%d%s ", n, tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute and print the length of each word before you print the word.

Here is a simple solution using `strcspn()`, a standard function that should be used more often:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[20] = "I Love India";
    char *p;
    int n;

    for (p = str; *p;) {
        if (*p == ' ') {
            putchar(*p++);
        } else {
            n = strcspn(p, " ");  // compute the length of the word
            printf("%d%.*s", n, n, p);
            p += n;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good to see a `strcspn()` solution here.  Could even use `const char str[20]...`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char str[20]="I Love India";
   char buf[20];
   int i,n,count=0;
   n=strlen(str);

   for (i=0; i <= n; i++) {
       if(str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\0'){
           buf[count] = '\0';
           printf("%d", count); /* Print the size of the last word */
           printf("%s", buf);  /* Print the buffer */
           memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)); /* Clear the buffer */
           count = 0;
       } else {
           buf[count] = str[i];
           count++;

       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

You will want to keep a buffer of the word that is currently being counted. (*buf*)
Increment *count* each time its not a space or 0/. Then, when it is a space or a 0/, print *count* first, then *buf*. Then, we will clear *buf* and set *count* to 0, so that the variable *i* is still incrementing through the entire string *str*, but we are inserting the words into *buf* starting from 0.

Comment: Thanks for giving the solutions. But it's give a output as "1I@4Love5India". There is no need of "@" in the output

Comment: @HareramShah It is working now, I had to add a null terminator to the end of the buf before printing.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong as you print the word before the length. So you need to calculate the length first then print it and then print the word.

It could be something like:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char str[20]="I Love India";
    size_t i = 0;
    while(str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')   // consider using the isspace function instead
        {
            // Print the space
            printf(" ");
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            size_t j = i;
            size_t count = 0;

            // Calculate word len
            while(str[j] && str[j] != ' ')
            {
                ++count;
                ++j;
            }

            // Print word len
            printf("%zu", count);

            // Print word
            while(i<j)
            {
                printf("%c", str[i]);
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to have two index variables for the string, `i` and `j`. The index `i` is at the words first character and index `j` is used for finding the end of the word. Once the end of word has been found, the length and the word can be printed.